# How to achieve this file size for a JPEG with these constraints?

Tags: image-quality, file-format, file-size, jpg

Is it possible to have a photo file meeting the following specifications (as required in India by NSDL for filing new PAN):

*Accepted format: JPEG, 200 DPI, Color and Dimension should be 3.5X2.5cm, Max File size 20kb*

When I set the document size to 3.5x2.5cm in Photoshop, resolution 200 pixels per inch, the image dimension becomes 276x197px and the file size 66.3Kb.

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear where you are getting that file size from. If you are referring to the size shown in the status bar at the bottom of your document, that isn't the final size of a JPG exported from the document, that gives information about the print size and estimated document size including layers etc.

If you need to export a JPG and file size is an issue then you can use the Save for Web tool. (In Photoshop CC there are now more export tools which you can use but I'm still using CS6).

[image]

As you can see in this example (which is the size as your specification), the Photoshop document shows a size of 159.3K/563.7K but the Save for Web gives us an image that is only 14.92K. You can adjust the quality and other options to lower the file size, but this will depend on your specific image.

There are also other tools available for further optimising image file size such as [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/).

Previous questions about reducing image file size:

- [How to reduce image file size more?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/64390/52050)
- [How to optimize images to improve pagespeeds / webpage loading times?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/51593/52050)

You can read more about exporting from Photoshop here:

- [Photoshop Help / Export artboards, layers, and more](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/export-artboards-layers.html)

Comment: Succeeded in uploading photo. Now, facing hurdle in uploading signature. Specification: Signature Accepted format: JPEG, 200 DPI, Color and Dimension should be 2X4.5 cms, Max File size 10kb. In Photoshop, Pixel Dimension becomes 157x354 pixels for 2x4.5cm and 200 DPI. After applying Save for Web option, the message I receive after uploading to NSDL server: Image size must be greater than 130x160.